# Can't login to AWS through CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I can't access the AWS through cli using `aws-google-auth`. When I enter the password I get this message:
[image]

With the same google account I am able to access the AWS through AWS Console, but not throughh `aws-google-auth`. Any idea?

Comment: It looks like you're not getting a response from the request to `accounts.google.com`. I know there's a way that you can enable debugging info from `aws-google-auth`; check the docs to find out how. Or talk to your internal IT team.

Answer (score 0):

After the new release of `aws-google-auth` came out, and I updated the packge, didn't have the issue anymore.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).